# node.js request.get in a loop -> very low perfomance

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I need to download around 5000 pages, I do it in a loop with request.get() inside like that, so every cycle runs with 400ms timeOut, but that didnt help, after around 1000 cycles, all just freeze and nothing downloaded or  I see `Socket hang up` errors. I think problem might be in system sockets limit, or something else. Here is my code:

```
function downloadDescription(url,iterator, downloadDescriptionCallback) {

    request.get(url, function (err, response, body) {
        if (err) {
            if(iterator < 3) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    downloadDescription(url, iterator, downloadDescriptionCallback)
                }, 1300);
            }else{
                log.warn("Request.get error link iterator limit");
                return downloadDescriptionCallback(null, "");
            }
        }else if (response.statusCode === 404) {
            if(iterator < 3) {//here I just change my Url, cause I dont exactly know the right path, and if I reach 3 iterator limits, I just forget him
                url =  desc_base_url + url.substring(url.indexOf("/", 27) + 1, url.length);
                iterator++;
                setTimeout(function(){ downloadDescription(url, iterator, downloadDescriptionCallback) }, 1300);
            }else{
                return downloadDescriptionCallback(null, body);
            }
        }else{
            return downloadDescriptionCallback(null, body);
        }

    }).on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err)
    });
};
```

So after time its around 100-200 cycles, I got a weird behaviour, donwloading time so slow and I even never reach the full 5000 pages, I think I can speedUp my perfomance some with tuning options?

Comment: Did you try disabling Agent usage?: `request.get({url: url, pool: false}, function ...)`

Comment: use `async.parallelLimit` or `async.eachLimit`